# Cucumber integration in testrail(java)

Tags: java, cucumber-java

i try to integrate cucumber scenarios in testrail, but i don't find some solutions, if somebody integrate it, can help?
i have scenarios write in java cucumber and need to integrate it in testrail. if it possible.
i try with api from documentation, but it is not work or i have some mistake

````
    public static String TEST_RUN_ID = "5400";
    public static String TESTRAIL_USERNAME = "username";
    public static String TESTRAIL_PASSWORD = "password";
    public static String RAILS_URL = "url";
    public static final int TEST_CASE_PASSED_STATUS = 1;
    public static final int TEST_CASE_FAILED_STATUS = 5;


    public static void addResultForTestCase(String testCseId, int status,
                                            String error) throws IOException, APIException {
        String testRunId = TEST_RUN_ID;
        APIClient client = new APIClient(RAILS_URL);
        client.setUser(TESTRAIL_USERNAME);
        client.setPassword(TESTRAIL_PASSWORD);
        Map data = new HashMap();
        data.put("status_id", status);
        data.put("comment", "Test Executed - status updates automatically");
        client.sendPost("add_result_for_case/" + testRunId+ "/" + testCseId + "", data);

    }

}```
````

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at [Railflow](https://railflow.io/) - it can parse Cucumber JSON reports and create/update tests and test runs in TestRail.

P.S. I'm developer of TestRail